# How do I deal with two near-identical release branches in Maven

Tags: maven, release-management

At work someone has committed a lot of changes into a project that are JDK 1.5 specific. Unfortunately, some of the production environment is still at Java 1.4, and so they have resorted to creating a dual branch consisting of a jdk1.4 version of /trunk.

This 1.4-branch is likely to have at least a one year lifetime, during which changes in trunk are merged into the jdk1.4 branch.

The question I was asked is if there was any best practices on dealing with Maven artifact ids in this situation? Obviously best practices would probably avoided getting us in this situation to begin with, but now that we are ... what to do?

We thought about giving the other branch a unique artifact id, such as "myapp-jdk14", while keeping every other identifier field (groupId, version) in sync. Any obvious downsides to doing this?

Answer (score 4):

You could use a classifier for this:

> **classifier:**
>   The classifier allows to distinguish artifacts that were built from the same POM but differ in  their content. It is some optional and arbitrary string that - if present - is appended to the artifact name just after the version number.
>
> As a motivation for this element, consider for example a project that offers an artifact  targeting JRE 1.5 but at the same time also an artifact that still supports JRE 1.4. The first artifact could be equipped with the classifier jdk15 and the second one with jdk14 such that 
>   clients can choose which one to use.

Source: http://maven.apache.org/pom.html

Answer (score 4):

In fact, there are 2 commonly used solutions for this:

1. Adding some special, custom suffix to artifacts' names, like `jdk14`. For example, [Bouncy Castle](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.bouncycastle) or [SLF4j](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-jdk14) use this strategy.
2. Using classifiers, that are in fact designed for such tasks like distinguishing variations about same artifact (exactly your case).

What is interesting from my experience, first solution is really more often used despite the fact that the second one is officially suggested for such stuff.

Personally, I use first solution, but - to be honest - I don't see any strong advantage (or disadvantage) of one solution against the other one.

Answer (score -1):

You can use your solution but I would suggest to have different version numbers.

For example:

```
1.0.X for JDK 1.4
1.1.X for JDK 1.5
```

That doesn't mean my suggestion is better than yours. Your solution has the advantage to see based on the artifactId which jdk it is for very obviously.

Comment: this breaks semantic versioning and confusres things when new minor releases are made - what follows 1.0.X for JDK 1.4?  it's a really bad suggestion.